# How to dynamically get the length of a div using JQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am developing a web application using AngularJS. I find myself in a situation where I have a bar (with the css I created a line) that must **dynamically lengthen and shorten**.
I know that JQuery scripts are sufficient to do this. For example, if my css is like this:

```
.my_line{
    display:block;
    width:2px;
    background: #FFAD0D;
    height: 200px; /*This is the part that needs to dynamically change*/
  }
```

I could in the controller resize the line (of `my_line` class) simply with:

```
$(".my_line").css("height", someExpression*100 + 'px');
```

The thing is, I would like to dynamically resize the line based on the size of **another div element** (Or, in general, any HTML element of my choice).
I don't know how to get (at run-time) the size of a certain page element in terms of height.
Only in this way I would be able to create a line that dynamically lengthens or shortens as the size of a div (or some other element) changes!
How do you do this? So I will avoid writing *hard-coded* the measures but I want make sure that they vary as the dimensions of other elements on the page vary

Comment: How does the height of the other element change? Can you not simply update the height of `.my_line` at the same time, using the same value?

Comment: No, the height of the other element changes because the user of that page can add rows to a table dynamically. It is not written "in code" how much the element must grow, but it certainly grows

Comment: And do you have control over the code which adds the rows?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helping:

```js
$(".my_line").css("height", $("#referenceElement").height()*5 + 'px');
```

```css
.my_line{
  display:inline-block;
  width:2px;
  background: #FFAD0D;
}
#referenceElement {
  display:inline-block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="my_line"></div>

<div id="referenceElement">Hi, I'm 5 time smaller than the orange line!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using the **setInterval** to track the div's height (you can do width as well) and storing it in a **previousHeight** variable and comparing it every interval

Then according to the comparison, it will determine if the height of the div has changed. If it has then it will change the height of the other div according to the height of the first div

You can create *multiple variables* and track *multiple elements* in the same **setInterval**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var previousHeight = parseInt($("#my-div").css("height"));
   
   setInterval(function(){ checkHeight(); }, 100);

   function checkHeight() {
   
    // Check height of elements here
    var currentHeight = parseInt($("#my-div").css("height"));
     
    if(currentHeight != previousHeight) {
      previousHeight = currentHeight;
      $("#dynamic-div").css("height", parseInt(currentHeight) + "px");
    }
    
   }
   
   $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#my-div").css("height", parseInt(previousHeight) + 5 + "px");
   })
  
})
```

```css
#my-div{
  background: #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

#dynamic-div{
  background: teal;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="my-div">
</div>

<button id="button">Increase div height</button>

<div id="dynamic-div">
</div>
```